# XSLT to return input xml as is, except replacing a string to another regardless where it may appear

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

My goal is to produce an XSLT output that is the same as the input, with the exception of the replacement of a string to another, regardless where it may appear. The string to replace can be data, xml tag name, namespace name URI or anything else within the xml document, I'd like it replaced either way.

Example xml input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ns:a xmlns:ns="http://www.toreplace.com" xmlns:nsB="http://www.toreplace.com/anything">
  <nsB:b>
    toreplace
    <toreplace>
      data toreplace
    </toreplace>
    toreplace
  </nsB:b>
</ns:a>
```

Desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ns:a xmlns:ns="http://www.replaceto.com" xmlns:nsB="http://www.replaceto.com/anything">
  <nsB:b>
    replaceto
    <replaceto>
      data replaceto
    </replaceto>
    replaceto
  </nsB:b>
</ns:a>
```

My best try so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy-of select="replace(., 'toreplace', 'replaceto')"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This produces output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    replaceto

      data replaceto

    replaceto
```

The problem I'm facing is that the output produced by the replace function omits everything but data, even though the same XPath expression (dot) does not omit anything in the following example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns:a xmlns:ns="http://www.toreplace.com" xmlns:nsB="http://www.toreplace.com/anything">
  <nsB:b>
    toreplace
    <toreplace>
      data toreplace
    </toreplace>
    toreplace
  </nsB:b>
</ns:a>
```

What causes the different behavior of the seemingly same XPath expression? How do I resolve this? Do I need a completely different approach to achieve my goal?

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. As is, the xslt you referred to does not alter namespace URI, tag name, etc - as you stated in your answer there. I am sorry but I'm new to xslt and I still cannot modify the referred xslt to work the way I'd like it to: as I try to modify the referred xslt, I experience the same problem I had before: the output misses everything but data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

    <!--Template to change namespace -->
    <xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri()[matches(., 'toreplace')]]" priority="1">
        <xsl:element name="{replace(name(), 'toreplace', 'replaceto')}" namespace="{replace(namespace-uri(), 'toreplace', 'replaceto')}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"></xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--Identical Transform -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--Template for Text Change -->
    <xsl:template match="text()[matches(., 'toreplace')]">
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(., 'toreplace', 'replaceto')"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--Template for Element name Change -->
    <xsl:template match="*[matches(local-name(), 'toreplace')]">
        <xsl:element name="{replace(local-name(), 'toreplace', 'replaceto')}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"></xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:element> 
    </xsl:template>

    <!--Template for Attribute Name and Value Change -->
    <xsl:template match="@*[matches(., 'toreplace') or matches(name(), 'toreplace')]">
        <xsl:attribute name="{replace(local-name(), 'toreplace', 'replaceto')}">
            <xsl:value-of select="replace(., 'toreplace', 'replaceto')"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<ns:a xmlns:ns="http://www.replaceto.com">
    <nsB:b xmlns:nsB="http://www.toreplace.com/anything">
        replaceto
        <replaceto>
            data replaceto
        </replaceto>
        replaceto
    </nsB:b>
</ns:a>
```

Comment: _The string to replace can be data, xml tag name, namespace name URI or anything else within the xml document, I'd like it replaced either way._ The solution provided will not replace the text within element names, namespace value as required.

Comment: @AniketV, Ahh, i miss that part.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help, Rupesh, thank you, your XSLT works beautifully for the first example xml I provided. However, it seems not to be generic enough. To demonstrate this, I extended my example xml with an additional namespace. Basically, what I would like to achieve here is to replace the toreplace string wherever it is in the input xml.

Comment: @Sely, Answer Updated. only thing change is second namespace is move to child element

Comment: Thank you for the update. Again, your xslt is not generic enough. "ns" and "nsB" are just examples of namespace names, they can be anything in different input xmls. Also, there can be a schema location declaration in the root node like xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.toreplace.com/anything" that needs to be changed. Simply put, I need all occurrences of "toreplace" to be replaced, regardless of the structure or content of the input xml.

Comment: @Sely, Answer Updated.

Comment: Thank you Rupesh, I really appreciate your updates. Your most recent version is pretty solid. The only issue still remaining is the one you noted in your earlier comment: the movement and redundant declaration of the namespace URI. Nevertheless, the resulting xml seems to work for me so the time critical issue is solved by you and for that I am very grateful.

Comment: @Sely, Glad to help you :)

Comment: @Sely, If this answer resolve your query, than accept the answer, so this question is marked as solved